# How can I get my hostname within a function?

Tags: c, hostname

the unix `hostname` program gives me an exceedingly simple way to get my "real" hostname (not localhost. For example, for me it's currently `unknown74e5[...]df7.att.net`). But how can I do this inside of my own code with C system calls? I'd like to get a `char *` that has this string in it so that I can pass it into `gethostbyname` and similar.

While I'm at it, I'd like also to know how I can get my IP address with UNIX system calls rather than relying on programs (or worse, whatismyip.com)...

Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that a system may have multiple IP addresses. Also, due to NAT, the external IP as seen by whatismyip.com might be different from what the host itself sees.

Comment: Also, why do you need to know your own IP? This is rarely needed. If you just want to listen on a socket, use `0.0.0.0` or allow the user to specify it. This is how most Unix servers work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gethostname(2)` is the POSIX-mandated C library function that powers the `hostname` program:

```
   int gethostname(char *name, size_t len);
```

Comment: Really? I thought it was just retrieving a value from the kernel.

Comment: @Joe Maybe you're somehow thinking of `gethost**by**name` ?

Comment: Yeah, that'll be it. Sorry. Ignore all my previous comments! :-)

Comment: The hostname has nothing to do with DNS. It's just he name of the host as defined by `hostname` and `/etc/hostname/`. `gethostname()` shall not be mixed up with `gethostbyname()`. However it is common practice for network hosts to set the hostname to the name one of the host's nic-ips resolves to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`uname(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/uname.html) which gets you a [`struct utsname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_utsname.h.html) filled with information. You're interested in `nodename`

```
struct utsname {
    char sysname[];    /* Operating system name (e.g., "Linux") */
    char nodename[];   /* Name within "some implementation-defined network". */
```

---

The `uname` function and `utsname` struct are also mentioned by POSIX and available on virtually all platforms. As Thomas mentions in the comments, glibc implements `gethostname` as a call to `uname(2)`.

Comment: They're equivalent on systems with GNU libc: "The GNU C library does not employ the gethostname() system call; instead, it implements gethostname() as a library function that calls uname(2) and copies [...] from the returned nodename field [...]"